# How can I make async versions of this generic function?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, generics

I have a WCF library that abstracts so much garbage work when connecting to a particular web service, and it's been working great! However, I'd like to update the library to allow async use but I've hit a roadblock with two particular generic functions that I use the fix some WCF issues and/or handle auditing in a generic form:

This function makes sure that the WCF request has three particular headers set from the adapter class, and deals with the exception handling in a particular way:

```cs
internal T PerformWCFServiceCall<TIn, T>(Func<TIn, T> wcfOperation, TIn ebsRequest) where TIn : class
{
    T retVal = default(T);

    try
    {
        // Set the EBS headers
        // It would be nice to constrain request as an instance of IEBSMessage but that's not a feature of the language :(
        (ebsRequest as IFunkyServiceMessage<funky_headerA, funky_headerB, funky_header>).EBS = this._ebsHeader;
        /*.. other code ..*/

        if (this.State != CommunicationState.Opened) { this.Open(); }

        retVal = (T) wcfOperation(ebsRequest);
    }
    catch (FaultException<ebsFault> ebsFaultEx)
    {
        // acknowledge the Faulted state and transition to Closed
        this.Abort();

        // handle or throw
        throw ebsFaultEx;
    }
    catch (FaultException faultEx)
    {
        // acknowledge the Faulted state and transition to Closed
        this.Abort();

        // handle or throw
        throw faultEx;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // acknowledge the Faulted state and transition to Closed
        this.Abort();

        // handle or throw
        throw;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

This function is used like this:

```cs
public getTypeListResponse GetTypeList(getTypeListRequest request)
{
    return PerformServiceCall(
        (getTypeListRequest) =>
        {
            return base.getTypeList(request);
        },
        request);
}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```cs
public async Task<getTypeListResponse> GetTypeList(getTypeListRequest request)
{
    return await PerformWCFServiceCall(
        async (getTypeListRequest) =>
        {
            return await base.getTypeListAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        },
        request).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Now, is it correct to change the method signature to:

```cs
internal async Task<T> PerformWCFServiceCall<TIn, T>(Func<TIn, Task<T>> callToPerform, TIn ebsRequest) where TIn : class
```

And the line:

```cs
var result = await callToPerform(ebsRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
retVal = (T) result;
```

What I get generally is the message: "`Task<T>` does not contain a definition for `GetAwaiter` and no extension method `GetAwaiter` accepting a first argument of type `Task<T>` could be found." and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Did you try it? Did anything go wrong when you did? (Also, the cast is unnecessary in both versions, `wcfOperation` already returns a `T` so you don't need to cast it.)

Comment: Sorry @ScottChamberlain, I just added that info - realized I didn't say that there was a problem.

Comment: On what line do you get that error?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain `await callToPerform(ebsRequest).ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: Is this running as part of a ASP.NET site, PCL assembly, Silverlight assembly, or in .NET 4.0 with the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package?

Comment: Ah, it's .NET 4 and not using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` as I didn't originally add the service reference with Task async, but I'm now going back through and adding it. Another project (new service ref, task-based async, etc) in .NET 4.5.2 seems to have no problem with the code.